# SQL Multiple sorting and grouping

Tags: sql, doctrine, dql

EDIT: I'm using DQL

I'm looking for help with an SQL query.

My table has a list of movies, each with a title, seriesName and seriesNumber. Is it possible to order them so the Titles are listed A-Z, but when a series occurs, that series is grouped together, with the seriesName being placed alphabetically as if it were inthe movieTitle column, and the entries in a series ordered by seriesNumber.

Bad explanation, but basically what I want is this:

```
MovieTitle                  SeriesName          SeriesNumber
Blade Runner                NULL                NULL
District 9                  NULL                NULL
Hot Fuzz                    NULL                NULL
I am Legend                 NULL                NULL
Fellowship of the Ring      Lord of the Rings   1
Two Towers, The             Lord of the Rings   2
Return of the King          Lord of the Rings   3
Lost in Translation         NULL                NULL
Matrix, The                 Matrix              1
Matrix Reloaded, The        Matrix              2
Matrix Revolutions, The     Matrix              3
Requiem for a Dream         NULL                NULL
This is Spinal Tap          NULL                NULL
Zodiac                      NULL                NULL
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: DQL, doing some stuff in Symfony2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM x
ORDER BY CASE 
   WHEN SeriesName is NOT NULL THEN SeriesName ELSE MovieTitle  END
   , SeriesNumber
```

You may have to do it this way

```
SELECT * FROM(
  SELECT *, CASE WHEN SeriesName is NOT NULL THEN SeriesName ELSE MovieTitle END SortOrder  FROM x
)
ORDER BY SortOrder,SeriesNumber
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried getting it to work in straight DQL, but it was a bit of a hassle, ended up using raw sql. Appreciate the help :)